# How can I create a new mailboxplan in Exchange 2010 powershell?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

May I know how can I create a new mailbox plan in exchange 2010?

Reading the doc from Microsoft, `Get-Mailboxplan` and `Set-Mailboxplan` commandlets are provided, but not a `New-Mailboxplan` commandlet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxplan?view=exchange-ps

Anyone has experience on it?

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is *Exchange Online* only. You need to refer to the old style [service plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-141/ff923279(v=exchg.141)) , which is a lost lore. I remember doing something like that more than 5 years ago, and a quick internet search does not help much.

In Exchange 2010 example service plans are stored in the folder

```
 c:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\ServicePlans
```

You need to add the new mailbox plan into an existing or new service plan, then reapply the service plan to the organization using `update-serviceplan -organization <your exchange organization>`  as explained [on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-141/ff923263(v=exchg.141))

Some more info [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/bec66348-9e76-40e3-bc6b-00b25e1d3319/add-another-mailbox-plan-in-a-service-plan?forum=exchange2010hosters).